# Типы хранимых данных в базах данных

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте. Объясните, пожалуйста, в общих словах, какого типа значения можно хранить в базах данных? Неужели все ограничивается числами и строками?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Многое зависит от базы данных которую вы используете. Если брать SQL Lite, то все ограничивается вообще строками. Если брать что то более тяжелое (MySQL, MS SQL и тд), то есть еще Date, DateTime, Blob (для хранения бинарных данных). 
Различные вариации тех же чисел (целые, с плавающей точкой, денежный формат), Булевый тип (Ложь, Истина). Это на вскидку все, уважаемое сообщество думаю сможет дополнить.

Comment: Неправда. SQLite имеет 5 видов данных, но динамическую типизацию. В некоторых случаях тип важен (например, при создании primary key).